# Blog post review process

Tags: discussion, blog

The [community blog](https://medium.com/language-learning-blog) is just that: a *community* blog, meaning its content is not up to the discretion of a single user, rather this community.

What can we do ensure that the community is in agreement about what is posted on the blog?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on the review process:

- An author writes a **draft**.
- They **notify potential editors/reviewers** of the draft by posting the link in the **chat**.
- An editor **reviews** the draft to check at least the following things:

  - **appropriateness** for the blog (which should not be a big deal);
  - **language** (grammar, spelling, ...);
  - the presence of a **link to a question, answer or tag** on the main site (since we want to drive more users to the site; use the "share" links instead of those from the URL bar);
  - correct **attribution** of images and other content from other sources (including licences of this content).
- The presence of a **copyright statement** and/or **licence**.
- A reviewer can optionally ask another reviewer to have a look at the draft (e.g. a non-native speaker of English asking a native speaker to check the language).

After this, the article should be ready for publication.

Comment: How will we determine who the editors and authors are?

Answer (score 0):

I propose we set up a post review system, of sorts. Once a post is finished being written, the writer will post a preview link somewhere* and wait for approval by 2** editors†. Once it has been approved, the post will be added to the scheduling queue to await publishing.

---

Variables that need to be confirmed:

*

- Chat?
- Meta? (probably not)
- Is there a post review mechanism on Medium?
- Somewhere else?

**

1? 2? 3? More?

†

- Editors?
- Writers?
- Community members?
- Someone else?

Comment: I think the draft should be announced in the chat. One reviewer is probably sufficient, but the reviewer can always ask for a second opinion (e.g. a non-native speaker of English asking a native speaker to check the language).